# Groovy AST Semantic Analysis Duplicate Class Definition

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, transformation, abstract-syntax-tree

I have this class that implements ASTTransformation and creates a getter and setter method for every field marked with a certain annotation:

```
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase=CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
public class Rewriter implements ASTTransformation {
public void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source) {
    List fields = nodes.findAll { it instanceof FieldNode }
    fields.each {
        MethodNode get = createGetter(it)
        MethodNode set = createSetter(it)
        source.getAST().addMethod(get)
        source.getAST().addMethod(set)
    }
}

private MethodNode createGetter(FieldNode f) {
    Parameter[] parameters = []
    ClassNode[] exceptions = []
    Statement state = new AstBuilder().buildFromString("return ${f.name}").get(0)
    return new MethodNode("get" + f.name.capitalize(), Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, ClassHelper.make(f.getType().name), parameters, exceptions, state)
}

private MethodNode createSetter(FieldNode f) {
    Parameter[] parameters = [
        new Parameter(ClassHelper.make(f.getType().name), f.name)
    ]
    ClassNode[] exceptions = []
    Statement state = new AstBuilder().buildFromString("this.${f.name} = ${f.name}").get(0)
    return new MethodNode("set" + f.name.capitalize(), Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC, ClassHelper.VOID_TYPE, parameters, exceptions, state)
    }
}
```

Running the following Test class

```
class Main {
    @Accessors
    int counter = 5

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            println getCounter()
    }
}
```

yields the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
User\groovy\meta\src\Main.groovy: -1: Invalid duplicate class definition of class Main : The source User\groovy\meta\src\Main.groovy contains at least two definitions of the class Main.
One of the classes is an explicit generated class using the class statement, the other is a class generated from the script body based on the file name. Solutions are to change the file name or to change the class name.
@ line -1, column -1.
1 error
```

What causes this? It seems to create the methods and add them to the source's AST fine.
I'm using Groovy-Eclipse 4.3

Answer (score 1):

You're very close to have a working AST transformation. Heres a few observations I made looking at and testing your code.

- In the `visit` method, the

  ```
  source.getAST().addMethod(...)
  ```

  seems to be the source of the `MultipleCompilationErrorsException` you're seeing. Replace it with

  ```
  it.declaringClass.addMethod(...)
  ```
- Also, in the `Main` class, you will need to create an instance in the `static main` method: `println new Main().getCounter()` should to the trick.
- Your get and set methods are identical to the default get and set methods provided by groovy. Even if you want to change this later, it will make it difficult to test right now, because there is no way to know whether it is your AST transformation that is being used or whether it is the methods provided by groovy. So you should at least temporarily change the behaviour to something "non-standard" (or change the method names). I tested the code by inserting a "+1" in the return value from the getter.
- One final note, which might be a matter of taste: I think it is much clearer if the annotation and the AST transformation have "matching" names. I.e. I would rename `Rewriter` to `AccessorsASTTransformation`.